# Wordpress Pagination does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create a wordpress theme, but I am not able to make the pagination work on the live version. On the localhost it's working just as expected, but on the live version it gives a 404 page each time. I know that there is a lot of answers about this topic, but I was not able to fix my problem. I've already tryed the following topics, among so many others but none of them helped me:

> - [How to include pagination in a Wordpress Custom Post Type Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41738362/how-to-include-pagination-in-a-wordpress-custom-post-type-query?noredirect=1&lq=1)
> - [wp paginate_links and query vars not working Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41397510/wp-paginate-links-and-query-vars-not-working-wordpress)

I would like to know if you guys can help me to figure out what I am missing here. I am trying to show my navigation panel at index file(my blog page).

```
get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="container">
    <main id="main" class="col-xs-12">
        <h3 class="title text-center">Notícias:</h3>

        <?php 
            global $wp_query;
            query_posts(
                array_merge( array(
                    'post_type' => 'news',
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'posts_per_page' => 3
                ),$wp_query->query)
            );

            while($wp_query->have_posts()) :
            $wp_query->the_post();

            get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'news');

            endwhile; 
        ?>
        <div class="text-center paginate">
            <?php 
                if(function_exists('wp_paginate')):
                    wp_paginate();  
                endif;
             ?>
        </div> <!-- .tect-center / Paginate-->
        <?php  wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
<?php
get_footer();
```

Right now I am using `Wp-paginate` plugin, but using `paginate_links()` functions gives me the same error, but both of them work on localhost. For the paginate link I've used the example from docs:

> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links.

Can somenon help me on that, please?

Comment: try to reset permalinks.

Comment: Please reset the permalinks

Answer (score 1):

Since it's working on your localhost flushing permalinks might solve your issue.

Step 1: In wordpress dashboard "Settings > Permalinks".

Step 2: Scroll down and click "Save Changes", no need to change anything.

Once done, rewrite rules and permalinks will be flushed.

Comment: Thanks Ali, but unfortunately that did not solve my problem.

Comment: Ok then, can you be more specific, is it showing pagination but redirect to 404 on click, or doesn't show anything.

Comment: redirects me to a 404 page

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below code.

I have used WP_Query function to get desired result - https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

```
<?php 

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 3
    );

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

while($the_query->have_posts()) :
    $the_query->the_post();

    get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'news');

endwhile; ?>
<div class="text-center paginate">
    <?php 
        if(function_exists('wp_paginate')):
            wp_paginate();  
        endif;
     ?>
 </div> <!-- .tect-center / Paginate-->
<?php  wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
```

Comment: Also make sure your page slug and content type slug are different.

Comment: I've tryed the code above, but now it does not show the wp_paginate links.. I will give a try with your code using the paginate_links().

Comment: You need to install wp paginate plugin and activate it.

Comment: My Slug is different from content

Comment: Also make sure Apache re-write module is enabled and .htaccess is up to date with proper lines to work with custom permalink structure.

Comment: It's active, with the original code it was showing but redirecting me to a 404 page. Now it does not show anything.

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
 # END WordPress